# AJAX POST size limit?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've seen a bunch of questions here about how to upload large strings of data using AJAX to PHP, however, in what I've seen, these questions usually ask how to upload strings of around 3MB. I need to upload a much larger string.

In my case, I have a `base64` encoded image with around 20 million characters (checked using `"theString".length` in JS). I've tried uploading it to the PHP server, but every time I check the value in PHP, it is null.

I have gone into `php.ini` and added `post_max_size = 100M` and `upload_max_filesize = 100M`. I also checked the `phpinfo` file to make sure that the changes took place. Still doesn't work. How many MB is a `base64` encoded string of this length? What should I do? I heard `POST` doesn't have a max upload size? Is this true? Let me know if you need to see some code. By the way, I have tried uploading strings of data that are shorter and they work just fine. The only changing factor is a much longer string.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may need to send it as multipart form-data, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0):

try changing 100MB to 128 MB
`post_max_size = 128M`
`max_upload_size = 128M`
and change the `max_ececution_time` to 300

Comment: the basic memory structure

Comment: yeah I changed `max_execution_time`. No change.